# Which is the correct way to install a service in Hortonworks?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm a bit confused about which is the correct way to install Oozie in a cluster (2 masters or namenodes, 2 workers or datanodes).

1) So basically, in the documentation you have a set of command line instructions that you can follow. I don't really know in which machine should I execute this shell instructions since I have 2 namenodes.

2) Then I also notice that using the Ambari UI, you can also use 'Admin' > 'Stack And Versions' > 'Add service' (on the service you want, this case Oozie).

3) Finally, also from Ambari UI, you can just go to 'Actions' > 'Add Service' and the 'Add Service Wizard' starts where I guess you can install new services.

Which would be the correct way to do it and how?

Comment: 2nd and 3rd will do same process but you will have UI to do task. This is easy and recommended for new users. If you are familiar with HDP stack and command line then go for first option. All of them are correct ways so decide the choice as per your familiarity with stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a beginner using a VM sandbox or a professional Hadoop administrator working on a huge live cluster, **you should almost always use Ambari to add a service**. That's what it's there for, after all. It drastically reduces the complexity and chance of failure when installing a service, by:

1. Letting you specify which nodes to install on.
2. Automatically generating valid configuration (no chance of mis-typing a port number and spending a day debugging!).
3. Moving all required files into the correct locations on the correct nodes with the correct permissions.
4. Running smoke tests to ensure installation is successful.
5. Giving you monitoring/admin of the service once it's running.

@Nachiket is right to say that your options 2 and 3 will have the same outcome. I always use `'Actions' > 'Add Service'` just because it's fewer clicks from the home screen.

There are only a few situations where you'd not use Ambari, primarily if you're installing an unsupported version.